# Magento 2 - How to add Font Family in admin panel wysiwyg editor?

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, cms-pages, font-family, editor

[image]

Need to add font family in wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to extend the TinyMCE editor.

**Step 1**

In file:

> magento_dir/lib/web/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template_src.js

find the line that looks like this and add your font

```
theme_advanced_fonts : "Custom Font=custom font alias;Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif ... ;
```

Then do the same with this file:

> magento_dir/lib/web/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template.js

```
theme_advanced_fonts : "Custom Font=custom font alias;Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif ... ;
```

These actions will add fonts to the dropdown menu in the editor.

Then you need to add a fonts file and include it in CSS files using the `@font-face` rule.

Edit file:

> magento_dir/lib/web/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css

Add code:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'custom font alias';
     src: url('../../fonts/custom_font_file.ttf');
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

Then put your font file by this path:

> magento_dir/lib/web/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/fonts

It should look like this:

> magento_dir/lib/web/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/fonts/custom_font_file.ttf

**Step 2**

Add font in your custom module to apply the font to the dropdown menu. It makes your font in the dropdown menu look styled.

> magento_dir/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/your-styles-file.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'custom font alias';
    src: url('../fonts/custom_font_file.ttf');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, you need to include the CSS files in the layout:

> magento_dir/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/your-styles-file.css"/>
</head>
```

Then put your font file by this path:

> magento_dir/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/fonts

It should look like this

> magento_dir/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/fonts/custom_font_file.ttf

**Step 3**

Then do the same like in **Step 2** for the frontend except layout XML file should be `default_head_blocks.xml`

*P.S. If anyone knows how to rewrite TinyMCE files in the custom module without touching it in the `lib` folder?*

Answer (score 1):

You can do It on several levels:

1. Directly for special WYSIWYG editor
2. For all WYSIWYG editors in Magento

Let's look for both solutions

- Define new module
  file-path app/code/Project/Wysiwyg/registration.php

Define module version
// file path app/code/Project/Wysiwyg/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Project_Wysiwyg" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

specify a solution for cms blocks app/code/Project/Wysiwyg/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_fonts" xsi:type="string">Fooo=bar,baz;</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Result is:

[image: Result is:]

2. The way for all editors is plugin the config model
   \Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface
   The Interface is responsible for TinyMCE parameters. You could mix something using after the plugin

Define app/code/Project/Wysiwyg/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
   <type name="Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface">
        <plugin name="project_wysiwyg_config"
                type="Project\Wysiwyg\Plugin\Config"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And create plugin
app/code/Project/Wysiwyg/Plugin/Config.php

```
<?php

namespace Project\Wysiwyg\Plugin;

class Config
{
    /**
     * Return WYSIWYG configuration
     *
     * @param \Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface $configInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Ui\Component\Wysiwyg\ConfigInterface $configInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject $result
    ) {
        if ($result->getDataByPath('settings/theme_advanced_fonts')) {
            // do not override ui_element config
            return $result;
        }
        $settings = $result->getData('settings');

        if (!is_array($settings)) {
            $settings = [];
        }

        $settings['theme_advanced_fonts'] = 'Baz=foo,bar;Bar Foo=baz,foo;';
        $result->setData('settings', $settings);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The result for the CMS Page is:

[image: The result for CMS Page]

Please define your list of fonts
And check that all of them added on adminhtml and frontend scope