# How to add custom fonts for magento 2 admin panel?

Tags: magento2

Anybody know how to change

> font-family

of admin panel in **magento 2?**

Comment: [Answer to this question alreday posted by other member please check this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205673/magento-2-how-to-add-font-family-in-admin-panel-wysiwyg-editor)